# Apache authentication specifics ... not quite working

Tags: apache-2.2

I don't understand why this isn't working for me. Here's my conf portion:

```
<Directory />
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Please Log In for Access"
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 111.111.111.111 111.111.111.112
   Satisfy any
   <LimitExcept POST>
     Require valid-user
   </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

However, the "Satisfy any" let's anyone through. If I change it to Satisfy all, the authentication shows for the Allowed IP and Non allowed IP's.

Help?

Comment: IT would help if you described what behavior you desire.

Comment: This seems to work, but still not sure why ...

    <LimitExcept POST>
     AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
     AuthName "Please Log In for Access"
     AuthType Basic
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
     Satisfy Any
     Require valid-user
     Allow from 111.111.111.1
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </LimitExcept>

Answer (score 0):

It looks okay to me, although a couple things to check

- LimitExcept only works from apache 2.0.51 upwards, make sure you have a compatible version.
- Make sure that the apache user can read the .htpasswd file properly

Also you can try to remove the `LimitExcept` for the moment and see if that helps, piecing out the config and trying it in small bunches is always a good trick.

Comment: Hi lynxman,
- apache is version 2.2.17

Comment: So looks like my recommendation worked, good!